# Access Registry Values of logged off Profiles

Tags: c#, registry, windows-task-scheduler

I have a C# application that needs to get values which they are stored in user profile in registry installing it in Windows Server 2012. I execute my application with Task Scheduler setting it 'run whether user is logged on or not' . To get registry values from user profiles I access through HKU with SID of user profile (like the code below).

```
                            using (RegistryKey rk = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.Users, RegistryView.Default))
                            {
                                using (RegistryKey key = rk.OpenSubKey(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User + "\\SOFTWARE", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree, RegistryRights.FullControl))
                                {
                                    foreach (var item in key.GetSubKeyNames())
                                    {
                                        file2.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + ": Getsubkeynames 2 :" + item);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
```

So my problem is I cannot access registry values of user profile after logging off. I'm curious if it's able to do that or not.

Comment: I think you should wrap it in a service if you want to be able to run it without being logged in

Comment: I think you can impersonate that user though

Comment: @TheGeneral Could you  please provide me the example how to do it?

Comment: Take a look at the second answer here, and the linked answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16477370/access-currentuser-registry-key-for-impersonated-user-compatibility-with-net

Comment: @Stefan This application should be able to work both log on and log off